# Google Speech API not working in Python sub-process

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, python-multiprocessing, google-speech-api

This problem is showing up only on a specific project in Google Cloud (on multiple VMs). The exact same code works perfectly on other projects and on my Mac.

I have a python module which is running streaming speech API with something like this:

```
responses = client.streaming_recognize(
    streaming_config,
    get_requests()
)
```

The code is based on the Google sample [here](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/streaming-recognize)

I can run this module directly and see that it is getting result callbacks. This is true even on the Google VM where later (see below) I have the issues.

Then I run the same module with `multiprocessing.Process` and then, the call to `streaming_recognize` just does nothing.
I used logging to see it is being called and the code continues to run. **I get no errors**.

But `get_requests()` is NEVER getting called.

I have tried different service accounts on each of the environment. But the failure shows only in the one project, regardless of service account used.

Any reason there should be a different behavior is a sub process?

**UPDATE:**
I found out that if I start the process instead with `subprocess.Popen` everything works correctly. And just as a reminder, this problem (difference in behavior based on how I started the process) happens only in one specific Google Cloud project, and not anywhere else.

Comment: Envisage your function as being deployed into a container that primarily includes (in this case) a Python runtime and doesn't include a shell

Comment: It seems impossible to me that `streaming_recognize` is called but not `get_requests`. A function cannot be called before all of its arguments have been passed. Could you double-check this, or elaborate on how you came to the conclusion that `streaming_recognize` is called but not `get_requests`?

Comment: @Andreas  `get_requests` has a while loop that is `yield`ing values.
I added log messages at the start of the function and inside the loop.
None of these log messages have been reached, only in the environment I have the issue.

Comment: This might be related to the timing of when you create the process worker. Note that there are side effects that result from sharing state across processes. The different spawning strategies from parent process can also influence behavior. For e.g. if you create the connection in parent, create Process worker, then pass that as arg to Process worker in target function, the connection will become read-only for both sides.

Comment: @skullgoblet1089 I would expect this behavior defined by the different spawning strategies, to carry between Google cloud projects. I see this issue just in one project. Not in others, and not when running on any development machine

Comment: @RonHarlev (1) spawning strategy: I generally agree with you, and it sounds like this may not apply to you as you say. However, if your Google cloud projects have vastly different resources allocated to them (num cores, mem) than you may see differences in behavior. A Python process with multiprocessing running on your local computer with 4 cores is not going to have the same resource footprint as one running on say a 32-core machine. Depending on the overall context of your run-time environment this may have surprising side effects and should be tested. I've seen this with numpy many times.

Comment: @RonHarlev (2) timing. If resource utilization seems stable as size of container changes, it's probably the timing of when you create the connection while you are interacting with the multiprocessing.Process. The clue that subprocess works but multiprocessing didn't may indicate that you need to "spawn" not "fork", the default on Unix, all else equal as I also suggested above. Hope that helps. https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.get_all_start_methods